# Laravel nested eager loaded models randomly missing during testing

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have the following relationship:

```
shipment -> hasMany -> shipmentPackages -> hasMany -> shipmentItem --> belongsTo -> product
```

I am eager loading the relationship before looping through them and trying to access the product.

```php
$shipment->shipmentPackages->load('shipmentItem.product')

$shipment->shipmentPackages->each(function($shipmentPackage){
   $shipmentPackage->shipmentItems->first()->product; // sometimes fails
})
```

When accessing the product through the eager loaded collection, I very occasionally get the error `Trying to get property 'product' of non-object`. In my test suite, it happens randomly across different tests. If I run the same test 10 times I might get one failure. The randomness of this is really confusing me...

If I do not use eager loading them it works 100% of the time. i.e.

```php
$shipmentPackage->shipmentItem()->first()->product; // this always works
```

It's almost like it is failing to load certain models to memory in my development environment (valet) but I have no way to be sure.

**Dirty Fix**

To further demonstrate the issue, this is a fix that works but is obviously not fixing the root of the issue:

```php
$shipment->shipmentPackages->load('shipmentItem.product')

$shipment->shipmentPackages->each(function($shipmentPackage){
   $this->getProduct(shipmentPackage); // always works
})

public function getProduct($shipmentPackage){
  try {
      return $shipmentPackage->shipmentItems->first()->product;
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      return $shipmentPackage->shipmentItems()->first()->product;
  }
}
```

Comment: A small note on naming conventions; if something returns a `hasMany()` relationship, you really should name it to match... `shipmentItem` is singular, so I'd expect it to return one (or none), but `shipmentItems` is plural, and conveys to the user that multiple records are being returned.

Comment: Next, the existence of a `hasMany` relationship, and eager-loading it does not guarantee that `shipmentItem->first()` will return a result. There's a query method `whereHas()` that scopes the results to ones that explicitly do have the relationship, but `load()` does not use that logic. A simple check is `$shipmentPackage->shipmentItem->first() ? $shipmentPackage->shipmentItem->first()->product : null` (although it's messy to read)

Comment: Thanks - I fixed the plural typo. So, in this case, the model does actually exist but it is just not being loaded in the eager load operation. I have added a messy fix above to demonstrate the issue further.

Comment: Interesting... There shouldn't be a reason `shipmentItems->first()` and `shipmentItems()->first()` return different results, regardless of loading or not, and by that extension, adding `->product()` should do the same (error or success). What's the query to generate `$shipment`? Are you able to do `Shipment::with()` instead of `$shipment->load()`?

Comment: I am only using `$shipment->load()` for this one, but I have tried with `Shipment::with()` too and get the same issue.

Comment: As I say... it does it randomly on different records. If I run a loop of 500 sometimes it will complete the loop and sometimes it fails within the first few iterations.

Comment: That makes pretty much 0 sense, unless the record(s) your checking aren't the same every time... Then I could chalk it up to different source/different results. Is that the case? Or is it the same `Shipment` instance (or instances) every time?

Comment: Eager loading loads the records to memory. I am wondering if somehow it woild be possible to not have the records loaded before they are accessed. I am pretty stumped on this one!

Comment: Nah, that shouldn't be the case. PHP is asynchronous; the next line of code will not execute until the previous one is finished. Time to start doing some logging; add `Log::info()` statements where the code fails, and keep running your tests; see if it's consistent when it does fail, etc etc.

Comment: I would like to see how you create the data in the test that fails, it could be there something is making your test flakey.